# Trying to convert from seconds to date

Tags: php

Okay so I have an array of results from a table, we have a start and end time we are retrieving. the start/end time would look something like this:

```
1345497551
```

Now I'm trying to convert this to a real time, for instance `1345497551` might become `2012/05/09 17:23:12`  or something. I've found a few things but none seem to work correctly. one solution I tried, according to what someone was saying on another question on here, was

```
$createdate = date('H:i:s',$numberofsecs);
```

where `$numberofsecs` was the time pulled in from the array. but this only ever outputs `17:00:00` repeatedly for every time we had available for testing.

How can I go about making this work correctly?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming that that's a standard unix timestamp string (seconds since midnight 1/1/1970), then you should be able to use [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) as you mentioned, but just modify the format string:

```
echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $numberofsecs);
```

The example you mention where you were always getting 17:00:00 could have been because your test cases were all only  datestamps, encoded as timestamps, and having an offset from GMT . . .

Comment: it looks like when I attempt that it does give me a date but its definitely not todays/yesterdays date like it should be. I tried that string with the number from the original post and I got 1969/12/31 17:00:00 echoed out to me. any other suggestions?

Comment: When I use the above `$numberofsecs` I get `2012/08/20 23:19:11`. I suspect you have a typo, so you're seeing the result of converting 0 to a date.

Comment: Ahh yes you're right I did have one, thank you! is there any reason, if the $numberofsecs was retrieved today, why it would state the date was 2012/08/20 instead of 2012/09/05? but at least its retrieving the proper thing now, thank you!

Comment: @user1650459 The most likely explanation is that your source data isn't what you expect it to be.  Garbage in, garbage out . . .

Comment: {{ date('Y/m/d H:i:s',90060) }}, Yes i just checked

Answer (score 5):

I have tried below code:

```
$ts = 1345497551;
$date = new DateTime("@$ts");
echo $date->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

output : 1345497551 = 2012-08-20 21:19:11